# Homeomorphism between $(0,1)^{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: general-topology

We already know that $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.Is it possible to generalize this homeomorphism and say that also $(0,1)^{\mathbb{R}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ if the answer is  yes , why we can do that ??

Comment: Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a homeomorphism, then $$(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{R} } \mapsto (f(x_i))_{i\in \mathbb{R}} $$ is a desired homeomorphism. This holds in both box and product topologies.

Comment: Which topology are you assuming for $X^{\mathbb R}$? There are several possibilities.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point. I was assuming (with no good reason, really) that OP was thinking about the product topologies. If that's not the case, my answer doesn't apply, of course.

Comment: I use the product topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Prove that for homeomorphic topological spaces $X,Y$ their product topologies $X^I, Y^I$ (for any $I$) are homeomorphic as well.

(Extend the homeomorphism $\pi \colon X \to Y$ coordinate wise to a homeomorhpism $\pi^I \colon X^I \to Y^I$.)